# Sky map for tropics

Tags: tropic

I like to use rotational sky maps to use in the field, but I have this only for latitude 50°N.   I'd like to have a similar sky map for tropics: 10°N. Do you know where I can order one?

Comment: questions about where to specifically purchase things, AFAIK, are off-topic for The Great Outdoors.

Comment: @studiohack, this is really a rare item so it requires a good know-how of where to buy it. And sharing know how is on-topic here AFAIK.

Comment: I agree this is on topic - it's not asking where the best place is for an item, just *anywhere* where a rare item can be purchased.

Answer (score 3):

[Skymaps.com](http://www.skymaps.com/downloads.html) offers free rotational style sky maps to print out in PDF form each month, including equatorial editions (scroll down half way) that are drawn for 0° but good to ±15°.

Comment: thank you. I know skymaps.com, I'm looking for something more detailed and possibly (but not necessarily) rotational (2 pieces of paper rotating against each other) so that it shows sky for particular time.

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought about Google Sky Map for Android or Star Walk on iPhone? These may give you what you need.

(I know, batteries run out, phones get wet etc., but these will show sky at a particular time)

Comment: thanks Rory, I thought of this, but Android is dead in tropics, since the battery lasts 2 days only and you cannot use normal replaceable AA batteries!

Comment: Yeah - not ideal, as I mentioned, although you can get some reasonable solar chargers...